# image insertion in database in android studio

Tags: android, mysql

I pick an image by capturing camera or select from gallery and then trying to send it another activity an through a button click I am trying to insert the image base64 value in the database . but the actual value is not inserted, please help me to solve the problem.Even if I want to send the image to another activity, the activity stop working. The code is following-

```
ib1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        ib1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                openGallery();
            }
        });
        ib2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2) ;
        ib2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                cameraCapture();
            }
        });

        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                /*im.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                im.buildDrawingCache();
                Bitmap bitmap = im.getDrawingCache(); */
                /*Drawable drawable = im.getDrawable();
                BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable);
                Bitmap bitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap(); */


              /*  Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) im.getDrawable()).getBitmap();


                byte[] pic =imageToString(bitmap); */



                if (pic.toString().matches("") || e1.getText().toString().matches("") ||
                        e2.getText().toString().matches("") || e3.getText().toString().matches("") || e4.getText().toString().matches("")
                        ||
                        b2.getText().toString().matches("") || b3.getText().toString().matches("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please! fill all the field", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                } else {

                    // startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,EventAdding.class));
                    Intent next = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EventList.class);


                    Bundle bn = new Bundle();
                    next.putExtra("image",pic);
                    bn.putString("event_name", e1.getText().toString());
                    bn.putString("date", b2.getText().toString());
                    bn.putString("time", b3.getText().toString());
                    bn.putString("event_address", e3.getText().toString());
                    bn.putString("email_address", e4.getText().toString());
                    bn.putString("tel_no", e2.getText().toString());
                    next.putExtras(bn);
                    startActivity(next);
                }
            }

        });



    }



    public void setDate(View v) {


        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthofyear, int dayofmonth) {
                b2.setText(dayofmonth + "-" + monthofyear + "-" + year);
            }
        }, year, month, day);
        dpd.show();
    }


    public void setTime(View v) {
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
        hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        min = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        TimePickerDialog tpd = new TimePickerDialog(this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourofday, int minute) {
                b3.setText(hourofday + ":" + minute);
            }
        }, hour, min, false);
        tpd.show();

    }

    private void cameraCapture(){
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
    }

    private static final int PICK_IMAGE = 150;
    Uri imageUrl;

    private void openGallery() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestcode, int resultcode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestcode, resultcode, data);
        if (resultcode == RESULT_OK && requestcode == PICK_IMAGE ) {
            imageUrl = data.getData();
            try {

                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(),imageUrl );
                // Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(bitmap));

                im.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            im.setImageURI(imageUrl);
        }


        if (requestcode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultcode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bitmap photo;

            photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            im.setImageBitmap(photo);//set image to Imageview


        }
    }


    private String imageToString(Bitmap photo) {

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
        String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return encodedImage;
}
```

In the 2nd activity-

```
 Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    img = bundle.getString("image");
```

Answer (score 0):

In the second activity, you are trying to get a byte array from the bundle using this line,

```
byteArray = bundle.getByteArray("picture");
```

But you did not attach the byte array to the bundle in the first activity.

Answer (score 0):

you have to insert the image as blob in database,

```
byteArray=getBayteArray(image);
```

then insert it to database having the blob type of column.
this is how you get byte array

```
 public static byte[] getBytes(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0, stream);
    return stream.toByteArray();
}
```

Comment: in the getBayteArray(image) method,is image used as the Bitmap, if used, so I get the bitmap of the cause bitmap make problem in my code

Comment: you have to get byteArray form bitmap,then insert it into db

Comment: How to get bitmap from the image